# WCF wsHttpBinding UserName client credentials exceptions

Tags: wcf, exception, configuration

Here is the situation.

We have a Windows Server 2003 running IIS 6.

And there is a WCF service. The most important configuration settings are:

```
<wsHttpBinding>
   <binding name="wsHttpBinding">
      <security mode="Message">
         <message clientCredentialType="UserName"
                  establishSecurityContext="false" />
      </security>
   </binding>
</wsHttpBinding>
```

- reliableSession is turned off by default,
- negotiateServiceCredentials set to false

Server uses self-signed X509 certificate called `TestWCFCert` and it is written in the  `<serviceCredentials>,<serviceCertificate>`.

And in the identity

```
<identity>
    <dns value="TestWCFCert" />
</identity>
```

For the client userName Authentication the server uses `customUserNamePasswordValidatorType`, where in the implementation no exception is thrown, so all clients are excepted.

Client side is on WinXp Sp3 machine and has very similar configuration.

It has same identity `<dns value="TestWCFCert" />` for service address checking.

Also it has installed `TestWCFCert` certificate for server authentication.

```
<clientCredentials>
    <serviceCertificate>
        <authentication certificateValidationMode="None" />
        <defaultCertificate findValue="TestWCFCert" 
                            storeLocation="CurrentUser" 
                            storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
    </serviceCertificate>
</clientCredentials>
```

And this is working.

While if somebody try to set `establishcontext` to true.

The next is going on: 2 messages are sent and received for some client/server talk. And on third message where method is calling server throws exception

> Cannot find the negotiation state for the context 'xxxx'.

So what is going on? `EstablishContext` does not work without `negotiateServiceCredentials`?

The next strange situation is if we try to set `negotiateServiceCredentials` to true (with disabled `establishcontext`). Then there is the exception on the client side 'The request for security token has invalid or malformed elements', and no exceptions on the server.

Service is published on the internet and the operation is very simple

```
string GetData(int number);
```

Also mex is httpGetEnabled. Client does not use proxy.